# jQuery grid / table data plugins

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins, datagrid, datatable

I have been trying to decide which jQuery grid / table data plugin to use.  The answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/159025/jquery-grid-recommendations) give a lot of good info, but the question is three years old and deserves a revisit.  From my research so far it seems that at this time either [DataTables](http://www.datatables.net/), [Flexgrid](http://flexigrid.info/), or [jqGrid](http://www.trirand.com/blog/) will be the way to go, but I want to make sure I have considered everything regarding those three and have not left out any other suitable contenders.  A suitable plugin will play nice with jQuery UI, and I am pretty sure the three I listed do.

Answer (score 0):

Jquery UI is developing a grid project here is the link http://wiki.jqueryui.com/w/page/34246941/Grid

for more details on jQuery grid take a look at this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/159025/jquery-grid-recommendations

Comment: Thanks for the first link, but I already linked to your second link in my question.  I also explained that that question is 3 years old, hence me asking pretty much the same question again.

Answer (score 0):

jsGrid is Lightweight Grid jQuery plugin http://js-grid.com/
It's simple and easy tunable.